# Partial image opacity in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, image, opacity

I want to know if it is possible to affect the opacity of only a certain color in an Image?

For example, I have a PNG image file that has a simple drawing on it (smiley face) and I set the backdrop to the color 'white' only. I want to use the image on a web page, but I want only the smiley face shown (no white backdrop).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in HTML or CSS but what you should do is open the image in a picture editor that supports PNG transparency and set your image background to `transparent` (or `opacity` = 0) instead of white.

Answer (score 0):

Not with CSS.  The best way to handle this would be to give your smiley face image a transparent background.  That way, you could put a colored element behind it whenever you want to change its color.